# Casting a string to an object

Tags: java, casting, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, copy-constructor

when I create an object of the class BinaryTreeNode ,  I want to pass two String in the Constructor rather than an object of the class BinaryTreeNode how can I do that.

```
        BinaryTreeNode(BinaryTreeNode left,BinaryTreeNode right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }


BinaryTreeNode b  = new BinaryTreeNode("B","A");
```

Comment: Quite Frankly, you can't. Unless there is another constructor of `BinaryTreeNode` you haven't showed us.

Comment: Create a constructor that takes two String(s)?

Comment: You can if there is a constructor which allows you to do so. Otherwise see if you can make one.

Comment: I suppose you could create a constructor that takes one String, and then call `new BinaryTreeNode(new BinaryTreeNode("A"), new BinaryTreeNode("B"));`

Answer (score 2):

Write another constructor that takes two `String` parameters.

```
    BinaryTreeNode(String left, String right) {
        //whose knows why I want to do this...
    }
```

You can't cast a `String` into a `BinaryTreeNode`, that would throw an `Exception`.

Comment: I would think this is not appropriate at all. Something like `BinaryTreeLeafNode(String val)` would make more sense to me..

Comment: Look at his prototype that takes two Strings.  I agree that in principle, this seems obtuse. 
`BinaryTreeNode b  = new BinaryTreeNode("B","A");`

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* possible to [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) any object to a type which it is not.

But that is fine, and I suspect it is not the root of the problem, because it *doesn't make sense* to treat a String object *as* a BinaryTreeNode - they have naught in common except that which they both inherit from Object.

Thus, I would either make the "node/leaf value" *part* of the BinaryTreeNode type or, I may introduce a leaf node type such as:

```
class BinaryTreeLeafNode extends BinaryTreeNode {
    public final String value;

    public BinaryTreeLeafNode (String value) {
        super(null, null); // got anything better? :|
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
tree = new BinaryTreeNode(
    new BinaryTreeLeafNode("Left"),
    new BinaryTreeLeafNode("Right"));
```

And perhaps if I wanted to hide the details, then an overload could be introduced:

```
public BinaryTreeNode (String leftValue, String rightValue) {
    this(new BinaryTreeLeafNode(leftValue), new BinaryTreeLeafNode(rightValue));
}
```

(I would advise *against* widening the left/right member and constructor types to to Object, as that will eliminate a good bit of type-safety.)